# How can I sort an array of strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, sorting

I have a problem with this program.I have to create an array of five strings element along with a copy of it and then I have to sort it in lexicographically.Can anyone help me?

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 5
#define L 100


int main() {
    char s[N][L],c[N][L],*str;
    int i,aux,sup,j;
    printf("Inserisci stringa: ");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
     scanf("%s",s[i]);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) 
      strcpy(c[i],s[i]);
    printf("Frase originale: ");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
      printf("%s\t",s[i]);
    printf("\n\nCopia: ");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) 
      printf("%s\t",c[i]);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<N;j++)
        {
         if(c[i]<c[j])
          {
           str=c[i][L];
           c[i][L]=c[j][L];
           c[j][L]=str;}
          }
        }
    printf("\n\nCopia ordinata: ");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
      printf("\t%s",c[i]);
 return 0;
}
```

Please suggest me any changes.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your question? This is very vague.

Comment: Your code is not very legible. I strongly encourage you to clean it up and make it easier to read.

Comment: I have to order the copy of the original array (c[N][L]) in alphabetical order

Comment: Use `strcmp` instead of `c[i]<c[j]`

Comment: `if(strcmp(c[i],c[j])) `          in this way?

Comment: `if(strcmp(c[i],c[j]) > 0){ char temp[L]; strcpy(temp, c[i]);strcpy(c[i], c[j]);strcpy(c[j], temp); }`

Comment: Now it works,thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To alphabetically order two strings you can use the function `strcmp(string1, string2)`.
The value returned R is:

- R < 0 if the first character that does match has a lower value in `string1` (i.e. `string1` precedes `string2` in alphabetical order);
- R = 0 if the strings are the same;
- R > 0 if the first character that does match has a higher value in `string1` (i.e. `string2` precedes `string1` in alphabetical order).

For more details see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/.

To then order the array of strings you can use different sorting algorithms, if you are a beginner I would recommend the bubble sort (see http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Bubble_sort for an introduction).

Lastly I would recommend a more clear indentation and naming of your variables, it will be very helpful when writing more complex code.

Good luck!